# Technical term for a survey scale with opposite values at both ends?

Tags: survey, scales

I am having trouble finding the technical term for a scale used in survey research with opposite values at both ends of the scale. For instance, how can I refer to a scale of the following kind:
In your opinion, who is responsible for health care?
Government (1) --- (2) --- (3) --- (4) --- (5) Citizens?

Comment: On a side note, I agree that this is a poorly worded question. You can just as well add "Employers" and/or "Medical providers" and/or "Insurance companies" to the issue, and respondents will be totally lost.

Comment: Agreed, thanks. Actually, it is not my scale, but found on a paper that I am reviewing.

Comment: Then you have something easy to pick upon as a reviewer :).

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a *poorly defined* scale as it's not clear what the intermediate values mean - a sharing out of responsibility, or an allocation of responsibility to mid-level bodies between Government & the citizenry, or perhaps something else.  (Furthermore the question could be interpreted as asking either about an actual or a wished-for state of affairs.) [Likert scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) are often used in surveys to measure the level of agreement or disagreement with a statement, commonly on a five-point scale from 'Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly agree'  - perhaps it's this term you're looking for. If you're asking specifically about scales where only the extremes are labelled, they're called *bipolar*.

Comment: Great, thank you. I will go with poorly defined. It is for a paper I am reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

[Semantic differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_differential) might be what you are looking for. To quote the link:

> Osgood's semantic differential was designed to measure the connotative
>   meaning of concepts. The respondent is asked to choose where his or
>   her position lies, on a scale between two bipolar adjectives (for
>   example: "Adequate-Inadequate", "Good-Evil" or "Valuable-Worthless").

Comment: Seems rather strained. The example uses nouns, not adjectives, & surely isn't intended to measure connotative meaning of concepts - it asks a straightforward question.